# Coq: Unable to Unify

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

student here, just started learning Coq. I'm essentially trying to prove that [] = a::l where (a:A) and (l: list A) is False, solving all subgoals. I found a nifty Coq Library function called nil_cons but I get an error when trying to apply it. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance!

[Error Message Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/430x5.png)

[Proof Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61zMr.png)

Comment: Can you post your proof attempt, including the point where you are getting the error?

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim I've updated my post with the proof attempt

Comment: This is not the right way to add the proof attempt, please look at other posts from [coq]  topic, which almost always contain a Coq attempt: they include text.  This is easier to use by would-be helpers who can copy-paste your text in their working environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell exactly what the result you're trying to prove means, but `nil_cons` is probably not the way to go.  That lemma allows you to derive `False` when you have already established that `[] = a :: l`. Your goal, on the other hand, wants you to prove `[] = a :: l` assuming a different set of hypotheses.